# Android: Unbelievable StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: php, android, string, exception

I send a get request to a php script on webserver that returns 3 lines of text. I handle the response from the server like this:

```
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
```

Than I parse the lines like this:

```
line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    String a = line.substring(0, line.indexOf('_'));
    String b = line.substring(line.indexOf('_') + 1);
}
```

And this keeps throwing a StringIndexOutOfBounds exception and I can't really see why. Im already using a similar method elsewhere in my project (with a different PHP script returnig different lines of text and with a different parsing) and it works perfectly fine. When I Log the returned lines to see if they are properly returned from the server, they are the same lines that PHP script sends.

And here is the fun part. When I was growing pretty desperate, I tried to measure the line using:

```
int l = line.length();
```

and this returned 11 with my line. Than, when I simply tried to display something using:

```
line.charAt(5);
```

it threw a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5. I realy don't know what is wrong with this. Does anyone have an idea? Thanks!

EDIT

This is the PHP script

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    print("{$row['id']}\n{$row['number']}\n");
}
```

This is my java code:

```
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    Log.v("connection - user list", line); //This line logs: 1_485963
    //But this doesent work
    String a = line.substring(0, line.indexOf('_'));
    String b = line.substring(line.indexOf('_') + 1);
}
```

Comment: indexOf returns -1 if it does not find things. -1 is no valid index.

Comment: For your first loop, are you definitely only passing it strings that contain at least one `_` that is not the final character? Can't explain the second bit, though :-/

Comment: You really should compare the result of indexOf both with 1 and the length of the line-1 before you try to extract substrings.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the '_' character is contained in the string? Otherwise 'indexOf()' will return -1

Comment: Yes, Im positive on that, when I display the line using Log.v, the entire String with '_' in the middle is displayed

Answer (score 4):

Most likely `indexOf` returns -1 and `line.substring(0, -1);` throws `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

**EDIT**
Could it be that you might be reading an invisible character/line after `1_485963` line?

Assume input is like this:

```
1_485963\n\n
```

Then in the log you would see only `1_485963` but the 2nd time loop runs it would crash.

Comment: Well, but how can it return -1 when the char it's index im looking for IS located in the String? And this also doesen't explain why the simple charAt throws an exception, when i'm simply asking it for a char in the middle of the string

Comment: Please post the whole relevant code. What you experiencing should not happen. There must be a problem somewhere else.

Comment: I tried to secure this as well using if(line.length() < 1) but it still didn't work. I seriously don't know whats wrong here. But I managed to overcome this by sending the data each in a separate line so I dont have to parse it. This works now

Answer (score 0):

First try to debug. OR else try this

I am pretty sure that line.indexOf('_') is not available in given string

1) first print log of the string and check '_' character is available.

try this to avoid  StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

```
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
if (line.indexOf('_') != -1) {
   String a = line.substring(0, line.indexOf('_'));
   String b = line.substring(line.indexOf('_') + 1);
    }else{
   // means that index is not found
   }
 }
```

And finally you told string len = 11
and when printing char at position 5 is throw error.

check what u r doing in between printing len of the string and printing char at postion 5.

FINALLY some times you might get junk character from the buffer input stream. becoz its passing from n/w. check that also.

Comment: This solves it but I dont get anything from it now, since all the data are thrown away at the if statement, because it just can't see the '_' in the string and I really dont know why, because it IS there. But I solved it by sending the data in separate lines so I dont have to parse them. Why this worked for me once and not again, I dont know, like I said, Im using the same approach elsewhere and it all works fine

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm getting old and blind but how does this

```
    print("{$row['id']}\n{$row['number']}\n");
```

produce

```
1_485963
```

Surely

```
print("{$row['id']}_{$row['number']}\n");
```

is what you need.
Apologies if that is not valid PHP as the syntax of that
has always refused to stick in my brain.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I pasted a newer version of my script where I go to another line instead of introducing '_' into the line